# Laravel 7 subquery with join

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I have two tables as customers and transactions. In the transaction, all the transaction related to the customer gets stored. Now I want all the data from the customer's table and only the sum of the 'received amounts received from the transactions table.

Below is query

```php
$customers = DB::table('customers')            
    ->join('transactions', 'customers.id', '=', 'transactions.custId')
    ->where('customers.status', 'Active')           
    ->select('customers.id', 'customers.custName', 'transactions.custTotalReceived as Received')
    ->paginate(100);
```

expected result as below I want

custId  | custName  |  Received

0001  | mdw       |  2000

0002     | dev    |  5000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `groupBy()` on the `customers.id` (and `customers.custName`) and `SUM()` on the `custTotalReceived`. Something like:

```
$customers = DB::table('customers')            
            ->join('transactions', 'customers.id', '=', 'transactions.custId')
            ->where('customers.status', 'Active')           
            ->select(DB::raw('customers.id, customers.custName, sum(transactions.custTotalReceived) as "Received"'))
            ->groupBy('customers.id', 'customers.custName')
            ->paginate(100);
```